# using axios POST for reactjs form ended up with an error 400- bad request

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

I am trying to pass conatactform data from the web to my aws lambda function but my http client axios runs into error 400 stating the request to be a BAD REQUEST and error stating :(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing) . This is the code that I am using at the moment.

-> reactjs code...

```
    const data = {
        firstname,
        lastname,
        email,
        message
    };

    axios.post('/prod/ContactFormLambda', data, {
        headers: { 'ContentType': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response);
    });
```

-> lambda function...

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sesClient = new AWS.SES();
const sesConfirmedAddress = " verified-email@email.com";

/**
 * Lambda to process HTTP POST for contact form with the following body
 * {
      "email": <contact-email>,
      "subject": <contact-subject>,
      "message": <contact-message>
    }
 *
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var emailObj = JSON.parse(event.body);
    var params = getEmailMessage(emailObj);
    var sendEmailPromise = sesClient.sendEmail(params).promise();

    var response = {
        statusCode: 200
    };

    sendEmailPromise.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        callback(null, response);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.statusCode = 500;
        callback(null, response);
    });
};

function getEmailMessage (emailObj) {
    var emailRequestParams = {
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: [ sesConfirmedAddress ]  
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: emailObj.message
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: emailObj.subject
            }
        },
        Source: sesConfirmedAddress,
        ReplyToAddresses: [ emailObj.email ]
    };

    return emailRequestParams;
}
```

What can I do better to make it to the end?

Comment: Axios will post the data as JSON and apply the correct headers by default. Have you tried just `axios.post('/prod/ContactFormLambda', data)`?

Comment: yes i did try axios.post('/prod/ContactFormLambda', data) but it will ended in the same error 400 bad request.

Comment: Alright, that's frustrating. Then it might be a backend error, and it's hard to say what might be wrong without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: i have a lambda function on the other end which i suspect to be having an issue !